# Does macOS still use Yarrow as it's cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator?

Tags: macos, kernel

I'm trying to understand if the XNU underpinnings of macOS (BSD) still use the Yarrow cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator?

I have looked through the source and it seems as if they switched to a DRBG NIST generator?

https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4903.221.2/osfmk/corecrypto/ccdbrg/src/ccdrbg_nisthmac.c.auto.html

There are very few references to Yarrow in the 10.14 XNU code compared with older versions of the Kernel, but 10.14 still contains this string in `key.c` :

```
/* Our PRNG is based on Yarrow and doesn't need to be seeded */
```

That said if you looked at older XNU Yarrow is littered everywhere.

**Source code for XNU:**

[Lots of Yarrow references in XNU 2782 - macOS 10.11](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-2782.40.9/)

[Very few Yarrow references in XNU 4903 - macOS 10.14](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4903.221.2/)

So, are Apple still using Yarrow?

I ask because Yarrow is only capable of generating 160bit strong keys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yarrow is gone.

The kernel CPRNG is a Fortuna-derived design targeting a 256-bit security level.

https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/security/seca0c73a75b/1/web/1

Ok! So I mailed Craig Federighi recently about this, concerned that macOS wasn’t capable of generating >128bit quality keys.

He responded!

> ‘The source you were referencing is out of date.  You can find more current informations here:   FIPS certification [document](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3431.pdf), section 7: "The NDRNG feeds entropy from the pool into the DRBG on demand.  The NDRNG provides 256-bits of entropy.”’

What a legend.

[image]

So yup, macOS and iOS are both capable of generating 256 bit entropy and creating quality CS keys for both ECC and Symmetric Key crypto.

## EDIT: Apple confirmed the kernel CPRNG is a Fortuna-derived design targeting a 256-bit security level.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Would you happen to know which versions of macOS include Fortuna vs Yarrow?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as of 10.14 Apple *are* still using Yarrow.

The source of [xnu-4903.221.2/osfmk/prng/random.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4903.221.2/osfmk/prng/random.h.auto.html) says *"...we retain Yarrow.*" and the subsequent code is conditioned on Yarrow being hard coded true:

```c
void early_random_cpu_init(int cpu);

/*
 * Wrapper for requesting a CCKPRNG operation.
 * This macro makes the DRBG call with pre-emption disabled to ensure that
 * any attempt to block will cause a panic. And the operation is timed and
 * cannot exceed 10msec (for development kernels).
 * But skip this while we retain Yarrow.
 */
#define YARROW 1
#if YARROW
#define PRNG_CCKPRNG(op) \
    MACRO_BEGIN          \
    op;                  \
    MACRO_END
#else
```

Assuming it is up to date, `man random` on 10.14.5 confirms this:

> ```
>  The random device implements the Yarrow pseudo random number generator algorithm and maintains
>  its entropy pool.  The kernel automatically seeds the algorithm with additional entropy during
>  normal execution.
> ```

Whether Yarrow is sufficient or not seems to be covered in your [other question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71367/yarrow-and-weak-cryptographic-keys-on-macos).